# change the color of a circle using jquery animate while it's rotating in y-axis

Tags: jquery, css

I'm new to j query 
I want to rotate a circle in Y-axis for 180 degree and have pink background color for 0 to 90 degree and have red background color for 90 to 180 degree with no combination of color .
 I insert j query UI and write this code

```
html
<body>
<div></div>
</body>
```

and my css is :

```
css
body {
}
div 
{
height:100px;
width:100px;
border-radius:100%;
background-color:pink;
transition:all ease-in-out 2s;
}
```

and my java script code is  :

```
$(function () {
$("div").click(function () {

    $(this).animate({
    backgroundColor: "blue",

    }, {
        duration: 0,
        step: function (now, fx) {


            $(this).css('transform', 'rotateY(180deg)');

        }

    });

});

});
```

and I don't know how  to define pink background for 0 to 90 deg
 and
define red background for 90 to 180 deg .

i appreciate if someone could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try utilizing jQuery UI , substituting `css` `transform` value to `transform` for `all` , utilizing `start` option of `.animate()` to set `transform` property of `div` , setting `backgroundColor` of `div` when `now` within `props` animated object greater than `89`, or equal to `90`

```js
$(function() {

  $("div").click(function() {
    var el = this
    , n = 180;

    $({props: 0})
    .animate({
        props: n,
      }, {
        start: function() {
          $(el).css("transform", "rotateY(" + n + "deg)")
        },
        easing: "linear",
        step: function(now, fx) {
          if (Math.round(now) > 89 || Math.round(now) === 90) {
            el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
          }
        },
        duration: 2000
      });
  });

});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  transition: transform ease-in-out 2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Really thank you. you did too much and i appreciate your time and knowledge  .thank you thousand times. but as i'm new to j query so I hardly understand it. may one day I become that much profession . it solved . and I should thank all of you :) and also i'm new to stack over flow. if there is something which I can do to promote you'r activation please let me know.thank you again

Comment: but would you please tell me what is this line use for?                   $({props: 0})
    .animate({
        props: n,
      }, {

Comment: @nedaDerakhshesh `.animate()` can be called on any jQuery object ; at  `$({props: 0}) .animate({ props: n, }` `props` is `this` object at `.animate()` where initial value is set to `0` , `n` is set to `180` , `.animate()` increments `props` from `0` to `180`

Comment: I really don't know haw to thank you and appreciate your help. it works and solved my problem. wish you to be succeed .

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the javascript solution, CSS animations can be used to accomplish the desired result, aside from reacting to a click event which you'll still use javascript for:

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    $("div").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('spinClass');
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border-radius:100%;
    background-color:pink;
}

div.spinClass {
    animation-name: spinimation;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    background-color: red;
}

@keyframes spinimation{
    0% {background-color: pink; transform: rotateY(0deg);}
    50% {background-color: pink; transform: rotateY(90deg); }
    100% {background-color: red; transform: rotateY(180deg);}
}
```

You can play with that in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2938ajy5/)

Comment: I really don't know how to thank you. you did a lot to me . thank you thank you thank you thousand times . i'm new to stack over flow and if there is some thing to do to promote your activation please let me know. thank you again.

Comment: Then welcome to SO :) We're not really here to promote ourselves, we just want to keep the most helpful answers easy to find for others in the future.  If an answer helps you in some way, you can "vote up" by clicking the up arrow on the answer and it seems you've already figured out how to accept an answer.  That's really all there is to it